# Intersections of supports constraint

Tags: optimization, constrained-optimization

Let $\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{y} \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $\text{supp}(\mathbf{x}) \subset \{1,2,...,n\}$ denote the set of indices such that $\mathbf{x}$ is non-zero.

What type of optimization problem can model the following constraint?
$\text{supp}(\mathbf{x}) \ \cap \ \text{supp}(\mathbf{y}) = \emptyset$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Suppose that $\mathbf{x}\ge0$ and $\mathbf{y}\ge0$. Then a necessary
and sufficient condition for $\mathrm{supp}\{\mathbf{x}\}\cap\mathrm{supp}\{\mathbf{y}\}=\emptyset$
is for the two vectors to be orthogonal, $\mathbf{x}^{T}\mathbf{y}=0$.
Indeed, this is the familiar strong duality condition for linear programming:
$$
\mathbf{x}_{i}\mathbf{y}_{i}=0\;\forall i\in\{1,\ldots,n\}\overset{\mathbf{x}\ge0,\;\mathbf{y}\ge0}{\iff}\mathbf{x}^{T}\mathbf{y}=0.
$$

In the general case, we may define $\mathbf{u}$ and $\mathbf{v}$
to bound the element-wise absolute values of $\mathbf{x}$ and $\mathbf{y}$,
as in
$$
-\mathbf{u}\le\mathbf{x}\le\mathbf{u},\quad-\mathbf{v}\le\mathbf{y}\le\mathbf{v}.\tag{*}
$$
It is clear that $\mathbf{u}\ge0$ and $\mathbf{v}\ge0$ are implicitly
enforced. Now, combining this with the orthogonality condition, the following
is a necessary and sufficient statement for $\mathrm{supp}\{\mathbf{x}\}\cap\mathrm{supp}\{\mathbf{y}\}=\emptyset$:
$$
\text{There exists }\mathbf{u},\mathbf{v} \text{ satisfying (*) and } \mathbf{u}^{T}\mathbf{v}=0.
$$
Note that the condition is generally nonconvex, and problems involving
such constraints are usually NP-hard. Some special cases, however,
can be solved in polynomial time using geometric programming or semidefinite
programming techniques.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Could you please elaborate why $\mathbf{u}^T \mathbf{v} = 0$ implies that the support intersection will be empty?

Comment: I'm essentially making the argument that $\mathrm{supp}(\mathbf{x})\cap\mathrm{supp}(\mathbf{y}) = \emptyset$ is equivalent to the condition $|\mathbf{x}_i| |\mathbf{y}_i| = 0$ for all $i$. Then I used a basic identity from linear programming to show that this is true if and only if $\sum_i |\mathbf{x}_i| |\mathbf{y}_i| = 0$

Comment: Do you have a reference regarding the last part of your first answer? A book or article where they are dealing with this type of constraint using any of the techniques you mention. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Which part? The NP-hard aspect, or the geometric / semidefinite reformulations? For the latter, Boyd & Vandenberghe have a couple of excellent reviews on geometric and semidefinite programming reformulations / relaxations / approximations for nonconvex problems.

Comment: I referred to the latter indeed; the special cases where an intersection of supports constraint can be reformulated in a convex problem.